# Should this Game of Thrones question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

This question was posted today: [What is the fight club theory?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131422/what-is-the-fight-club-theory)

The OP is asking about a particular fan theory relating to the *Game of Thrones* TV series, of which they've heard the name but want to know what the theory actually says. The question has been closed as "unclear what you're asking"; however, at least one of the close-voters VTCed the question for being poorly researched:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this shows zero research. A simple google search would answer this. – [Aegon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/54887/aegon)

As I pointed out very quickly, **being poorly researched is a reason to downvote, *not* a reason to close-vote.** Since it seems perfectly clear (at least to me) what the OP is asking, I'm worried that others may have voted to close for the same reason. IMO, this is a valid question, albeit poorly researched, and therefore should be reopened.

**What do others think? Should this question be reopened or stay closed?**

<sub>Disclaimer: I was the one who answered it.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The question should be (and was) reopened

This is a question about a popular fan theory. As laid out in the most-upvoted answer to [Are questions about fan theories allowed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6937/are-questions-about-fan-theories-allowed), we can even ask questions that deal directly with fan theories:

> For example, if you have seen a popular fan theory somewhere else and
>   you don't understand why it makes sense, or what evidence there is to
>   support it, that probably is the kind of question you could ask here.

It seems clear that asking the *identity* of a fan theory should also be on-topic, if asking the specifics of it is.

In particular, this is also a question that seeks a definition of a particular term in the fandom. We have many such questions that were well-received and not closed. For example, ["Wheel of Time", Perrin's PLOD](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128470/wheel-of-time-perrins-plod).

As explained by the mod who reopened it, while the question may be downvoted for being easy to answer (i.e. showing no research effort), it is on-topic and should thus remain open.

Comment: Another part that perhaps could use repeating, on the off chance that it'll penetrate the heads of the "OMG it's right there on the first page of Google CLOSE CLOSE CLOSE" types, is that **we want to be that first result on the first page of Google**. And that's not going to happen if we close every question that happens to have an answer hidden in among the tripe on some fan site somewhere.

Comment: @Martha exactly, which may be in part supported by the fact that the [General Reference close reason was burninated](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/should-we-burninate-general-reference).